# Set order of bootstrap versions for angular application between angular.json and index.html import

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I work on this project that have been refactored with ngX-Rocket and Angular 7. Bootstrap 4 and ng-bootstrap were added to the project. Before that bootstrap 3 was used alone. The angular 2 pages that we had before refactoring are using bootstrap 3, but some of the new pages are using bootstrap 4. The problem is that the new bootstrap is overwriting styles from the old bootstrap 3, messing up the pages.

The way that boostrap 3 is included is by adding them in index.html:

```
.....
        <link href="../../../styles/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="../../../styles/css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
....
```

bootstrap 4 is added from Angular.json:

```
.....
 "styles": [
              "src/main.scss",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css" 
            ],
            "scripts": [ 
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js",
              "node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more.js",
              "node_modules/highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.js"
            ]
...
```

My skill level on configuring Angular app and CSS are not high, so I might misunderstand some concepts. I have some ideas to solve this:

1 - Find a way to make bootstrap 3 priority higher than bootstrap 4. This would be good cause all the pages will work as before
2 - Overwrite bootstrap 4 styles, with some custom ones, but 1:1 with bootstrap 3. I don't really like this.

Any though?

Comment: Combining 3 and 4 is a really bad idea. It’s probably faster, and definitely cleaner to simply upgrade the 3 styles to version 4. Thank me later 

Comment: I know that is a bad idea, but I was put in this situation and I don't know if I can change anything. In case I will be able to, I remember that I investigated what it wold takes to change the version from 3 to 4 some times ago, and I remember that a lot of changes that needs to be done to have the same style. And even If this is feasible, I don't know if I will not have style mismatch between NG-Bootstrap that is used on angular page and simple bootstrap that is used on non-angular pages.